# Wordpress plugin to create posts list style

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to find some wordpress plugin that creates a custom post type as a list (example "TOP 10 Best Wordpress Plugins"), where you can add or remove items. I'd like to create posts like Listverse.com or Whatculture.com. If anyone knows about such plugin, please advise.

Thanks!